# Why is UITabBarController returning a "..should support at least one orientation" message?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

I subclassed UITabBarController in order to override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` so that I can support landscape mode in certain circumstances. When I run this, the tab bar controller gives me the following message when the overridden method returns `NO`

`The view controller <...0x644f50> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.`

Any suggestions on how to get ride of the message other than return `YES` all the time in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you return NO, it means that your view controller can't be displayed on any of the 4 orientations.

You should think which orientations you want it to support and use the `orientation` parameter they give you to accept those orientations.

For example, if I wanted my view controller to support portrait and landscape right, this would be my implementation (This could be reduced to a line, but I'm expanding it for the sake of clarity):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation{
  if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) return YES;
  if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) return YES;
  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape() and UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait() to handle which specific orientation you want the UIViewController to support.